# DbExtensions SqlBuilder raw query does not make sense

Tags: sqlbuilder, dbextensions

I've been trying to use DbExtensions.SqlBuilder and have encountered a strange behaviour similar to the one in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187755/get-raw-sql-statement-with-dbextensions-sqlbuilder)

Basically when I do

```
var query = SQL
   .SELECT("ID")
   .FROM("TABLE")
   .WHERE("Column1 = {0}", 1);
```

Rather than getting the raw sql to be

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE Column1 = 1
```

I get the following instead:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE Column1 = {0}
```

Which doesn't seem right. Even the answer to the question I referenced doesn't seem to make sense to me. Why is the `WHERE` clause not formatting the string correctly?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you do some research on why use **parameterized SQL**.

Comment: @MaxToro ... I did all the research I could carry out and did not find anything useful. If you are aware of some page that explains why the example I provided in this question behaves the way it does, then that would be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get raw sql statement with DbExtensions SqlBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187755/get-raw-sql-statement-with-dbextensions-sqlbuilder)